# Change a popup window to a tab window

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any way to change a popup window to a tab window? I have a web page, by clicking a button this page changes to a popup window, I want to know if it is possible to use the same button in popup to change this popup to normal tab? any suggestion?

Comment: browsers give very little control to the website when it comes to choosing either a popup window or a new tab. It's mostly user preference. If you're using popups at all, you might want to consider switching to a more modern interface where you manage your own popups in the page.

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-url-in-new-tab-using-javascript

Answer (score 2):

The web browser / user decides whether a page opens in a new tab or in a new window. There is no interface to reliably influence this decision.

Sorry to disappoint!

Answer (score 0):

**if you want open a same window:**

```
<a href="url">click</a>
```

**if you want to open a new tab:**

```
<a href="url" target="_blank">click</a>
```

or

```
<a href="url" target="_newtab">click</a>
```

Comment: The first link will open in the same tab. The second and third versions will open in a new tab in the same window or a new window depending upon the web browser, it's preference settings and the users actions. I don't think this answer adequately addresses the question as I understand it.